# Typo3 Flexform CKE Presets

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, flexform

is there a way to configure the Presets of the CKE-Editor in Flexforms.

The Extension does not have any tables.

Typo3 version >8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can set the Preset of each Flexform / TCA field individually. For Flexforms in XML:

```
<enableRichtext>1</enableRichtext>
<richtextConfiguration>full</richtextConfiguration>
```

The docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/ColumnsConfig/Type/Text.html#richtextconfiguration